# Installation of 3rd party soundcard driver

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, compiling, soundcard

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`. I got a new PCI soundcard with 3rd party divers: `aqprox 32bit pci`.

> CHIPSET
>   C-Media CM8738
>   PCI-6CH-CX

In the linux drivers folder I have this files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 greenarfun greenarfun   2534 feb 25  2001 cmpci
-rw-r--r-- 1 greenarfun greenarfun 105333 jul 11  2001 cmpci.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 greenarfun greenarfun  10870 feb 23  2001 Config.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 greenarfun greenarfun 716059 feb 25  2001 Configure.help
-rw-r--r-- 1 greenarfun greenarfun   9606 nov 28  2000 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 greenarfun greenarfun   2971 feb 25  2001 README
```

In the `README` file I have those instructions:

## STEPS TO BUILD DRIVER

1. Backup the Config.in and Makefile in the sound driver directory
    (/usr/src/linux/driver/sound).
    The Configure.help provide help when you config driver in step
    4, please backup the original one (/usr/src/linux/Document) and
    copy this file.
    The cmpci is document for the driver in detail, please copy it
    to /usr/src/linux/Document/sound so you can refer it. Backup if
    there is already one.
2. Extract the tar file by 'tar xvzf cmpci-xx.tar.gz' in the above
    directory.
3. Change directory to /usr/src/linux
4. Config cm8338 driver by 'make menuconfig', 'make config' or
    'make xconfig' command.
5. Please select Sound Card (CONFIG_SOUND=m) support and CMPCI
    driver (CONFIG_SOUND_CMPCI=m) as modules. Resident mode not tested.
    For driver option, please refer 'DRIVER PARAMETER'
6. Compile the kernel if necessary.
7. Compile the modules by 'make modules'.
8. Install the modules by 'make modules_install'

---

First problem comes in step 3, i have 4 linux folders:

```
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 feb 18 20:36 linux-headers-3.16.0-30
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 feb 18 20:36 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 may 23 20:01 linux-headers-3.16.0-38
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 may 23 20:01 linux-headers-3.16.0-38-generic
```

I tried with `linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic` but I got stuck in step 5, I can't find options Sound Card Support and CMPCI driver in `make menuconfig` and `make config` is really long and I don't know how to configure only one option or group....

Any idea how can I continue?

Comment: You forgot to tell us the model of the soundcard and where you downloaded the driver. http://approx.es/index.php?route=soporte/descargas doesn't look like the right place to me. Also you seem to have downloaded a release from 2001. I assume that the driver is already integrated or that the source code of the driver is incompatible with current Linux Kernels.

Comment: updated question with chipset model.... drivers came with installation cd of the hardware

Answer (score 1):

C-Media CM8738 chips [are supported by ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-C-Media), the card should be working without 3rd party drivers. Does it show up in the sound settings and play sound? Have a look at the following page if not: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

I think I found the [product page](http://approx.es/APPPCI51) for the card including updated Windows drivers, no Linux drivers later than 2001 though.

Comment: nope, it does not show in sound settings...I can see the motherboard integrated soundcard but not the CM8738 one....